# Jupyterlab extension install offline

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Can Jupyterlab extensions be downloaded and installed later on offline?
If so, how?

In the [documentation](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/extensions.html) it says:

> You can also install an extension that is not uploaded to npm, i.e., my-extension can be a local directory containing the extension, a gzipped tarball, or a URL to a gzipped tarball.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

How?

Answer (score 1):

[This github issue](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/4494) details the following solution. I tried it and it worked on the Bokeh jupyter lab extension.

> - outside, do a jupyter lab install of all extensions of interest
> - copy $PREFIX/share/jupyter/lab/static from the outside machine onto a shared/thumb drive
> - inside, overwrite/create that same folder

Make sure jupyterlab isn't running when you replace the static folder.

This is a temporary solution, and a more active discussion of the plans to make this process easier can be found [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/2065)